# Can a compiler, that generate a source code from a simple text, be considered as a source-to-source compiler?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction

I'm writing a compiler to generate a JSON code from a random simple text but I didn't understand the type of these kind of compiler. can I consider it as a source-to-source compiler?

> A source-to-source compiler is a compiler that takes the source code of a program written in one programming language as its input and produces the equivalent source code in another programming language.

(the problem is the input is a text, not a the source code of a program written in one programming language)

Or is there another type  for these kind of compilers?
and thank you

Comment: You could call it that, but it's pretty pretentious, don't you think?

Comment: It is a **transpiler** if you relax your semantics of what constitutes source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, a source-to-source compiler is understood to

> translate between programming languages that operate at approximately the same level of abstraction

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler)

Thus, I would argue -- that if by "random simple text" you mean a simple English phase -- you are just writing a regular old compiler.

I.E., I would consider English a "high-level language," and JSON a relatively "low-level language." Thus meaning that you are compiling from a higher level of abstraction to a lower level of abstraction -- just like a regular compiler.